# Laravel - Passing var into view after valdiation

Tags: php, validation, laravel

How can I pass some variables (like $validation->failed()) into my view?

```
    if ($validation->fails()) {

        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation);
    }
```

this is my method to go back.

Why is this not working?

```
    if ($validation->fails()) {

        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation)->with('failed',$validation->failed());
    }
```

Telling me there is now variable called "failed" or similar. 
Thank you!

Comment: Does anyone now something?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the Laravel documentation for passing validation errors to views: http://laravel.com/docs/validation#error-messages-and-views

Your first method is correct - it will pass the Validator instance you created to your view, as well as flash all error messages to your session. Therefore, to access these errors in your view, you will do something like this:

```
<?php echo $errors->first('email'); ?>
```

Comment: that's the problem. It's fine, but I also need the error types! And this I can only get within the controller with failed(). But It's somehow not possible to pass this array into my view. It's not working with with() and others fail to.